# Best method to bulk comment/uncomment debug lines of code?

Tags: python, debugging

I have a python script that consists of one very lengthy loop containing if/elif statements. To debug the flow of the loop I have a print statement under each if/elif block with a #debug trailing comment as per the following:

```
if my_var1 == "foo":
    print(my_var1)#debug
    perform_various_calculations()

    if my_var2 == "foobar":
        print(my_var1, my_var2)#debug
        pass
```

This is fine while I'm still developing the script, but once I'm past the development stage I'd like to easily toggle these print statements. The script does contain *other* print statements that I would *not* want to comment out, so something simple like a find/replace print to #print would not work.

I thought about putting together a custom print function that would only print if a Debug flag was set, but I'd prefer these numerous lines were commented out altogether.

Comment: Even if the answer provided by @kindall is valid and answers your needs I would suggest using the built-in [`logging` module ](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) which has plenty of cool features and can achieve exactly what you want. It has pretty low learning curve and lots of examples to benefit from.

Comment: Thanks bvidal. For this one script I'm happy with the quick/simple __debug__ check, but that was an interesting read. For the project at large though, the built-in logging module will be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck. Python has a `__debug__` flag which is set to `False` if you start the interpreter in optimized mode (`-O` command line flag), and `True` otherwise.

The best part is, when you use `if __debug__:`, Python strips out the branch of the `if` statement that won't be executed, along with the `if` statement itself. Only the code that can actually be executed remains.